# java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: The user 10350 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, version, google-play-console

getDeviceId is deprecated and for android targetSdkVerion 29 it is causing issue.

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: The user 10350 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers.
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
        at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getDeviceId(ITelephony.java:10441)
        at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId(TelephonyManager.java:1653)
        at com.imnos_mobile.data.source.telephony.TelephonyManagerSourceImpl.getDeviceId(TelephonyManagerSourceImpl.kt:154)
        at com.imnos_mobile.data.repository.telephony.TelephonyManagerRepositoryImpl.getDeviceId(TelephonyManagerRepositoryImpl.kt:38)
```

Comment: You got any solutions to fix this ?

Comment: Got any solution? facing the same issue